# Maintain multiple Visual Studio user options (suo) profiles

Tags: visual-studio-2008, multiple-monitors

I work in two environments with Visual Studio 2008: my laptop and my laptop+external monitor. When I work with a second monitor, I like for my solution explorer and other non-code windows to be on the second monitor, and my laptop screen to be just code files. It's a bit of a pain to rearrange windows every day as I switch between environments. Is there a way to better manage my user options? I could manually switch out my .suo files before starting VS but that seems to be just as annoying. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your settings and the position of your windows to a file, and then import this file while VS is running. To solve your problem, you'd set VS up the way you like it without your external monitor, then export your settings. Then, set it up for you monitor, and export. When you attach or remove your monitor, just import the appropriate setting file.

[This article should demonstrate where the import/export options are.](http://en.csharp-online.net/Visual_Studio:_Export_and_import_settings)

Comment: The downside to this approach is as you tweak your settings on a daily basis, you have to re-export your settings. I was hoping for something more like a profile manager for browsers

Comment: please update the link, page doesn't seem to exist.